# Troubleshoot which apps kill battery

Tags: iphone, battery

My 9 month old iPhone 6 would last just 5 hours after a full charge. Apple told me the battery diagnostics look good, and to reset the phone after backup.

I just got 10 hours use and nearly 40 hours standby. In other words, nearly good as the day I got it. Given that I had a few dozen apps, I'm looking for advice how to find the one(s) that were the battery killers. Is it simply of matter of looking at the list of apps used and noting the ones I used during a low time-to-dead-battery time?

Comment: If you go into 'Settings' -> 'Battery' and scroll down, there's a list of apps (from iOS 9 at least I believe) which shows what proportion of battery they've used.  If you tap the clock icon, it also shows you the usage and standby time

Comment: Got it. My oversight. I know the list, but I thought it was % by time, not by battery use. Curious, then why didn't the Apple tech send me to this list in the first place? Although I suppose the reset was the easy way to prove this battery is still fine. Back to my Mac to reload my backed up phone.

Comment: When you say "reset" you mean to factory settings, i.e. wipe it? Often starting with a fresh install can resolve issues since possibly corrupted settings files are cleared out, etc.

Comment: Yes - reset to factory setting. Which was fine for the test, i.e. to confirm that a fresh phone had great battery life and the battery wasn't to blame. But now, I need to see how long the charge lasts, now that my backup is restored.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 9, under `Settings > Battery` there is an itemised breakdown of the most battery-consuming applications you have, their on-screen time and background time, and the amount of battery they consumed.

Here is an example:

[image: battery breakdown]